# How many ways can I form a word using the letters in the word "Mixture" if all the vowels have to be at the beginning?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I thought of it this way:
You have 6 ways (from $P(3,3)$) of arranging the vowels that have to go at the beginning.
You then have four letters (consonants) left to order. The number of ways you can do this will just be $P(4,4)=24$.
Am I correct in assuming the answer to the question will be $6 \cdot 24=144$, or is there a gap in my calculations?

Comment: Looks correct too me.

Comment: Thanks! It really gives you a confidence boost when you're starting combinatorics and you start to get the hang of it.

Comment: No problem. You may not get an official answer to this question as any answer is just going to say "Yes" then potentially just reword/explain your working.

Comment: Seems correct but I just want to point out that this wouldn't work if "Mixture" didn't have all distinct letters.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct.

There are $3!$ ways to arrange the three distinct vowels in the first three positions.  There are $4!$ ways to arrange the four distinct consonants in the remaining four positions.  Thus, by the Multiplication Principle, there are $3! \cdot 4!$ ways to arrange the letters of the word MIXTURE if all the vowels must be at the beginning.